# How to refresh a method state?

Tags: java

I want to refresh method state after first call sleep()

Here's what I've tried

```
public class MyClass {

    private static boolean eatCalled = false;
    private static boolean sleepCalled = false;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        eat();
        sleep();
        sleep();
    }

    private static void eat(){
        System.out.println("Om nom nom");
        eatCalled = true;
    }

    private static void sleep(){
        sleepCalled = true;
        System.out.println("Z-z-z...");
        if(eatCalled){
            System.out.println("Good");
            sleepCalled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to see: Om nom nom, Z-z-z Good, Z-z-z. But I get Om nom nom, Z-z-z Good, Z-z-z Good. How can i get desired one?

Comment: I'm not sure why don't you expect to see the last "Good" print. It prints exactly what it should print ;)

Comment: I'm new in Java so I don't have enough knowledge to set this. That's why I'm here in hope to get answer.

Comment: change the last line: `sleepCalled = false;` with `eatCalled = false;`

Comment: HUGE thx! I would kiss you

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 if(eatCalled){
            System.out.println("Good");
            sleepCalled = false;
        }
```

to

```
if(eatCalled){
            System.out.println("Good");
            eatCalled= false;
        }
```